# google maps api javascript loading kml, set zoom and center

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, kml

I'm loading 4 different kml files based on user interaction. The default action when loading the KML with the following code:

```
SW4KML = "http://kml.url"
var sw4KmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({url: SW4KML});
sw4KmlLayer.setMap(map);
```

Is that it zooms to the boundaries of the KML layer. What I want is to be able change the zoom to be one or two less and also move the center of the map slightly to the right.

I've got as far as using 'preserveViewport: true'

```
SW4KML = "http://kml.url"
var sw4KmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({url: SW4KML, preserveViewport: true});
sw4KmlLayer.setMap(map);
```

but I haven't quite figured out how to go from there, I tried changing the map options to the lat long and zoom I wanted and then reloading it, but then for some reason my kml layer isn't loaded.

If anyone has had to do this in the past, please let me know how you went about it :)

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't reload the map, just change the center and zoom to those you want.

Comment: You mean like this? http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_toggleKmlLayers.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it would be to use the union of the default viewports of the KmlLayers.

```
    var G = google.maps;
    var layers = [];

function computeBounds() {
  var bounds = new G.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i=0; i<layers.length;i++) {
    if (layers[i].getMap() != null) {
      if ((typeof bounds == "undefined") || bounds.isEmpty()) bounds = layers[i].getDefaultViewport();
      else bounds.union(layers[i].getDefaultViewport());
    }
  }
  if (!bounds.isEmpty()) map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

function toggle() {
  if (!this.kmlLayer ) {
    this.kmlLayer = new G.KmlLayer(
        'http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kmz/' + this.id + '.kmz',
        { preserveViewport:true } );
    this.kmlLayer.myId = layers.length;
    layers.push(this.kmlLayer);
    G.event.addListener(this.kmlLayer, "status_changed", function() {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML += this.url+':'+this.getStatus()+"<br>";
    });
    G.event.addListener(this.kmlLayer,"defaultviewport_changed", function() {
      this.bounds = this.getDefaultViewport();
      computeBounds();
    });
  }

  if ( this.kmlLayer.getMap() != null ) {
    this.kmlLayer.setMap( null );
  } else {
    this.kmlLayer.setMap( map );
  };
  computeBounds();
};

function initialize() {
  var layers = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  var options = {
            center: new G.LatLng(34.9, 137.3),
            zoom: 10,
            mapTypeId: G.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
            scaleControl: true,
            overviewMapControl: true,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
              style:G.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU }
      };

  map = new G.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);

  for (var i=0; i<layers.length; i++) {
    layers[i].type = 'checkbox';
    G.event.addDomListener(layers[i], 'click', toggle)
  };
};

G.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_toggleKmlLayers.html)

Comment: Thanks geocodezip,that looks good but a little complex for me so I will spend some time going through it.